# Reverse model relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, model, laravel, relationship

I'm trying to get the related posts of a post, based on its tags.

My post (id 1) has several tags attached to it, i.e. tag (id 1-3) this means that my post has 3 tags. Based on those tags, I'd like to show other posts that have this tag(s).

My Tag Model:

```
<?php namespace Digitus\Base\Model;

class Tag extends \Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'tags';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function posts()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Digitus\Base\Model\Post');
    }

}
```

My post model:

```
    <?php namespace Digitus\Base\Model;

class Post extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('title','body', 'author','slug');

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Digitus\Base\Model\User', 'author');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Digitus\Base\Model\Tag');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Digitus\Base\Model\Comment');
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Digitus\Base\Model\Categorie');
    }
}
```

In my view I currently have:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 panel panel-info">
    <p>Gerelateerde berichten:</p>

            <?php 
            $posts = Digitus\Base\Model\Post::all();
            $tags = Digitus\Base\Model\Tag::all(); ?>
            @foreach($posts as $post)   
                @foreach($post->tags as $tag)
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">{{ $post->title }}</div>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach


</div>
```

But it doesn't really show the posts which have the same tags, it just throws all my posts out. Also, I tried adding some sort of filter to it, so there won't be any duplicate posts (same post show up 2+ times) but this also failed at my end.

I'm not looking for direct answers, more for directions and suggestions etc.

Comment: Could you be more explicit than "doesn'þ do the right thing"?

Comment: sorry @TomMacdonald, i edited

Comment: to do what you want you need one more nested foreach, although it's NOT the solution, as it would casue n+1 problem (many many db queries). You must read about eager loading http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do, but mind there will be run 3 db queries, so maybe you'd like some joins instead

```
<?php 
// don't do this in the view, better in controller, service or whatever and just pass $posts to the view
$posts = Digitus\Base\Model\Post::with('tags.posts')->get();
?>
@foreach($posts as $parentPost)
    @foreach($parentPost->tags as $tag)
        @foreach($tag->posts as $post)
            <?php if($post->id == $parentPost->id) continue; ?>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">{{ $post->title }}</div>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

----- edit:
In your Tag model you don't return nothing from relation, so just add return:

```
public function posts()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('Digitus\Base\Model\Post');
}
```

Comment: I think 'tags.posts' needs to be 'Tags.Posts'

Comment: You are wrong ;) in with() you call relations, not the models.

Comment: Hmm I am using it in a production app like that and it is working, so maybe both work?

Comment: Definitely not here, but you may have relations named Tag and Post, then it will work.

Comment: Tested. Both work. :-) I take my earlier comment back!

Comment: I tried this, but it returns a error: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object 

** I'm still reading the eagerloading stuff **

Comment: On the page of the post (where the code is rendered)

Comment: Jeroen, I mean where in the code the error occurs - on what method

Comment: Hehe, sorry.. tbh, i have no idea

Comment: Check the error message, it will tell you everything. You have stack trace there

Comment: Sorry, i'm unable to paste a screencloud or the entire code.

So i'll just paste the line that is highlighted in the error: $relation->addEagerConstraints($models);

Comment: It's hard to tell then.. Try this Post::findOrFail(1)->tags; Tag::findOrFail(1)->posts; if both work then your relations are correct and the code I enclosed will work too. Otherwise paste your models, controller and the error here http://laravel.io/bin

Comment: Though, when i do 'Tag::findOrFail(1)->post' it returns null.
And when i do 'Tag::findOrFail(1)->posts()' it also returns null.

(thought i'd share)

Comment: Oh wow, that hurts! I kinda feel stupid now.. that i didn't notice that. As far as i can see now, it works like it should! But it also adds the current page to the loop. But no probs, you helped me further than i could have gone myself. So i'll try to search stuff for that myself. 

Anyway, thanks both!

Comment: you sure? It should not add current post as you have in the loop if statement which excludes it

Comment: I'm very sure hehe. my current post title = 'eerste post', and it's included in the 'related posts' section

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)   
     @foreach($post->tags as $tag)
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">{{ $post->title }}</div>
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

you are iterating over all tags of all posts, and outputting the post title.

So for a post that has 3 tags, you will output the post title 3 times.

What you might do is this:

```
<?php $posts = Digitus\Base\Model\Post::with('Tags.Posts')->get(); ?>
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @foreach ($post->tags as $tag)
        @foreach ($tag->posts as $relatedPost)
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">{{ $relatedPost->title }}</div>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Not tested, but as far as I understand how Eloquent eager loading works, it should work.

**EDIT:**

The above would output all posts actually, so if you want the related posts of a single post, this is the way to go:

The following should output an array with a single post in it:

```
<?php $posts = Digitus\Base\Model\Post::with('tags.posts')->where('id', $id)->get(); ?>
```

which you then 'iterate' over:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @foreach ($post->tags as $tag)
        @foreach ($tag->posts as $relatedPost)
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">{{ $relatedPost->title }}</div>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: If i manually add a id, it also returns this error: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object

Comment: Try adding a get() between the with() and the find().

Comment: Just to be clear, the '->find($id)' is searching for the post id right? 

If that's the case, than it still returns the same error. I also added ->get() between with() and find()

Comment: Hmm, research suggests to do this differently. Check my edit in a minute.

Comment: Also, I was using 'Tag.Post' instead of 'Tags.Posts' or 'tags.posts'. My bad.

Comment: Yeah, that's the one that wouldn't work, like in my comment previously ;)